# What are the min/max voltage/current values the gpio pins can handle?

Tags: gpio

I want to start using the GPIO pins but I am worried about short circuits or using too much amperage and frying my raspi. What are the Min/Max Voltage and Current values rasppi can handle? What is the typical voltage and current? How sensitive is raspi to short circuits and things like that?

---

I have seen boards that are designed to 'protect' your raspi:

- http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1734

I don't really want to 'extend' the usefulness of my raspi I just want to protect it from getting fried by my GPIO pins. I'm intending on making a buffer circuit that will prevent my raspi from getting damaged from experimenting with the GPIO pins.

Comment: You will get a lot of wild speculation amongst the replies.  While data on the pi's gpio's is limited, most modern ICs will tolerate _temporary_ shorts between a driven output and ground, the supply rail powering it, or another output.  What they often will not tolerate is even brief connection to a higher voltage supply, such as a 5v pin on the same connector.

Comment: To be safe, use a breakout board. If you don't want to buy one then it's trivial to create your own [protection circuit](http://elinux.org/RPi_Tutorial_EGHS:GPIO_Protection_Circuits)

Comment: Provided you aren't using extremely high speed protocols, just using 1K series resistors may be a good balance of protection and simplicity; any jury-rigged solution (especially if it has active devices requiring power) runs the risk of introducing additional places for accidental shorts...

Comment: You can refer this link http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals . this would help you.

Comment: Some additional discussion here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/397388/practical-limits-on-raspberry-pi-gpio-pin-voltages

Answer (score 61, accepted):

## TL;DR

- This is a **3.3V device**.

  - Using 5V peripherals requires a [logic level converter](https://www.adafruit.com/product/757).
- Output

  - Maximum total of all pins 50 mA.
  - Default 8 mA max per pin. (Returns to this configuration after reset.)
  - Software configurable from 2 mA to 16 mA. Do not source or sink more than what you've configured.
  - Don't drive capacitive loads.
- Input

  - Threshold of 1.8V
  - Maximum 0.5 mA
  - Use a 6Kohm resistor to ensure that current from a 3.3V source cannot exceed 0.5 mA

    - ( *3.3<sub>V</sub> / 6000<sub>Ω</sub> = .00055<sub>A</sub>* )

## References

from: http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#General_Purpose_Input.2FOutput_.28GPIO.29

> GPIO voltage levels are **3.3V** and are **not 5V tolerant**. There is
>   no over-voltage protection on the board - the intention is that people
>   interested in serious interfacing will use an external board with
>   buffers, level conversion and analog I/O rather than soldering
>   directly onto the main board.

This is easily handled with a [bidirectional logic level converter](https://www.adafruit.com/product/757).

from: http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi/gpio-pin-electrical-specifications#rpi-gpio-input-voltage-and-output-current-limitations

### GPIO pins set to input

> These are 3.3 volt logic pins. A voltage near 3.3 V is interpreted as
>   a logic one while a voltage near zero volts is a logic zero. A GPIO
>   pin should never be connected to a voltage source greater than 3.3V or
>   less than 0V, as prompt damage to the chip may occur as the input pin
>   substrate diodes (shown as parasitic FETs in Figure 1) conduct. There
>   may be times when you may need to connect them to out-of-range
>   voltages – in those cases the input pin current must be limited by an
>   external resistor to a value that prevents harm to the chip. I
>   recommend that you never source or sink more than **0.5 mA** into an
>   input pin.

As @ AutomatedMike noted in the comments, you can insure this with a 2 Kohm resistor **per volt**. ( *3.3<sub>V</sub> / 6000<sub>Ω</sub> = .00055<sub>A</sub>* )

### GPIO pins set to output

> The Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins are quite versatile, and **you can modify**
>   many of their characteristics from software. You can turn on/off input
>   pin hysteresis, limit output slew rate, and control source and sink
>   current drive capability from **2 mA to 16 mA** in 2 mA increments. These
>   properties are set for the GPIO block as a whole, not on a pin-by-pin
>   basis.

---

> To prevent excessive power dissipation in the chip, you should not
>   source/sink **more current** from the pin than **its programmed limit**. So,
>   if you have set the current capability to 2 mA, do not draw more than
>   2 mA from the pin.

---

> Source/sink current capability does not limit the current into or out
>   of the pin, but only specifies the maximum current for which the
>   output signal high/low voltage specifications will be met. If misused,
>   output pins can be damaged by excessive current irrespective of the
>   source/sink current programmed. **After a reset**, the RPi comes up with
>   the GPIO outputs set to **8 mA drive** capability.

---

> Current sourced by the outputs is drawn from the 3.3 V supply, which
>   can supply only 50 mA maximum. Consequently, the maximum you can
>   source from **all the GPIO outputs simultaneously is less than 50 mA**.
>   You may be able to draw transient currents beyond that limit as they
>   are drawn from the bypass capacitors on the 3.3 V rail, but don't push
>   the envelope!

### Caution:

There are additional considerations for capacitive loads. You really should read [the document](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi/gpio-pin-electrical-specifications#rpi-gpio-input-voltage-and-output-current-limitations) that is heavily quoted here.

Comment: 0.5mA seems overly conservative, and would make the RPi useless for interfacing with most sensors, which typically draw at least a couple mA. [These docs](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi/gpio-pin-electrical-specifications) say the RPi is configured by default to sink/source 8mA and can be configured to sink/source up to 16mA.

Comment: @Cerin, you are correct that I quoted the conservative number. Did you notice that you linked to the same document that I quoted (but without the anchor)? If people want to push the envelope, they need to read that document and learn more than I am teaching here. I point them in that direction. I just don't want to be responsible if they source more than 50mA cumulatively.

Comment: The 8ma and 16ma figures refer to pins configured for output. 0.5ma is for pins configured for input.  Just ensure that there's always at least (Vss * 2Kohm) resistance between Vss and the pin then no more than 0.5ma can ever flow in to the input.

Comment: What would be acceptable current limit if I connect voltage greater than 3.3V on a GPIO in output True state? (Zener diode solution in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353218/p-channel-mosfet-switch/) @AutomatedMike