# RS232 to Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: serial, pi-zero, rpio

I know this may be a dumb question but can you connect a RS232 Tx, Rx, and Ground from a device directly to the Rx, Tx and Ground on a Raspberry Pi Zero without having to get a Max3232 or something similar to that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the significant differences in the voltage levels **it is not safe to directly connect any RS232 signal lines to the Pi's GPIO**. Even if the voltage of some RS232 drivers might be as low as 3 V, the logic one (called "mark") is represented as a negative voltage which will kill the Pi.

RS232 ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Voltage_levels)):

> The standard specifies a maximum open-circuit voltage of 25 volts: signal levels of ±5 V, ±10 V, ±12 V, and ±15 V are all commonly seen depending on the voltages available to the line driver circuit. Some RS-232 driver chips have inbuilt circuitry to produce the required voltages from a 3 or 5 volt supply. RS-232 drivers and receivers must be able to withstand indefinite short circuit to ground or to any voltage level up to ±25 volts. The slew rate, or how fast the signal changes between levels, is also controlled.

Raspberry Pi GPIO:

GPIO voltage levels are 3.3V and are not 5V tolerant. Voltages below 0V and above 3.3V are outside the operating voltage range.

See also:

- [What are the Electrical Specifications of GPIO pins?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/60218/19949)
- [What are the min/max voltage/current values the gpio pins can handle?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/3209/19949)

Comment: In addition to the voltage difference, even if you limited it to 0 - 3V it would not work as the polarity is inverted